# Why pg_wal dir does not clean up while logical replication

Tags: replication, postgresql-10

my main question - why pg_wal dir is extremely growing up?

I have two postgresql instances.

The first was set up as master:

```
wal_level: "logical"
max_wal_senders: 5
max_replication_slots: 10
```

Also, I was enable archiving for pg_wal:

```
archive_mode: on
archive_command: 'gzip < %p > /.../data/pg_wal_archive/%f'
```

After that, `PUBLICATION` was created for some of my tables (not `ALL TABLES`)

For `replication` psql instance - I using default psql config, only created `SUBSCRIPTION` to master.

And I have two questions:

1. I run some script on master, which pulling ~ 10 Gb data to one table, which was **not included** in the PUBLICATION. And, I see, that my `pg_wal` dir size is increasing anyway. Why?
2. Why pg_wal dir does not cleaning? Is it normal? Looks like I have some data for restore table which is not using in replication, how to delete this data?

Comment: Looks like `archive_mode:` should be `off`, and files in `pg_wal` will be auto replaced... Will check it...

Answer (score 0):

archive_mode is used for for archiving, regardless of standby configuration. It can be used for point in time recovery. So when you perform DML on any table, it will generate WAL.

For cleaning up you can use archive_cleanup_command from recovery.conf

Comment: Yep, still reading psql docs, looks lime my mistake was in turning on archive_mode.
Still have a lot of questions about `wal`, if my replica was going down - should I expect growing up `pg_wal` dir?

Comment: well, if standby goes down and recovery.conf was responsible for cleaning up, then pg_wal will increase. I would suggest creating a job to clean up your old WAL as per your retention requirements.